# Оптимизация: volatile и встраивание функций

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ассемблер, оптимизация

И вопрос, и в то же время просто хотел поделиться своим удивлением. Просматривал сегодня свои листинги, и наткнулся на забавный результат оптимизации компилятором из VS 2008. Локализовал его в следующем примере:

```
unsigned int rol(unsigned int v,char n)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax,v;
        mov cl,n;
        rol eax,cl;
    }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    volatile int a=4;
    std::cout<<rol(a,2);
    return 0;
}
```

результат компиляции с оптимизацией по скорости (то место, которое у меня вызвало недоумение, остается неизменным и при оптимизации по размеру) следующий:

```
00401CA0  push        ecx  
00401CA1  mov         dword ptr [esp],4 
00401CA8  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp] 
00401CAB  mov         dword ptr [esp],eax 
00401CAE  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp] 
00401CB1  mov         cl,2 
00401CB3  rol         eax,cl 
00401CB5  mov         ecx,dword ptr [__imp_std::cout (406204h)] 
00401CBB  push        eax  
00401CBC  call        dword ptr [__imp_std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<< (406208h)] 
00401CC2  xor         eax,eax 
00401CC4  pop         ecx
```

С первыми двумя командами все ясно - пушем выделяем 4 байта на стеке под одну локальную переменную ну и собственно присваиваем ей значение 4. С 3-ей всё тоже вроде ясно - переменная volatile, поэтому её необходимо прочитать. Что мы имеем с 4-ой командой. Тело функции **rol** оптимизатор встроил в **wmain**, но почему-то(???) решил передать **v** не в регистре, а все-таки выделить под неё память на стеке. Каким образом он это делает? Он судя по всему считает, что раз к **а** в тексте дальше нигде нет обращений, то стало быть можно использовать эти "освободившееся" 4 байта для этой цели. Далее мое внимание  ничего не привлекало.

Логика работы вроде ясна, за исключением решения о передачи **v** через стек, а не через регистр. Но в итоге то получается просто абсурдная на мой взгляд вещь:

```
00401CA8  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp] 
00401CAB  mov         dword ptr [esp],eax 
00401CAE  mov         eax,dword ptr [esp]
```

Первые две строчки можно просто выкинуть без потерь, получив выигрыш и по скорости и по размеру. Но ведь это же *оптимизатор*, он должен генерировать так или иначе оптимальный код, а он генерирует код, из которого можно просто строчку за строчкой без потерь выкидывать, не абсурдно ли?

Comment: Попробовал с g++ -O3 -S  правда без __asm { ... } (в gcc другой синтаксис ассемблера). 

Ничего лишнего, все inline. 4-ка кладется в стек, потом грузится в %eax, сдвигается (поскольку roll в С++ нет, я написал << (sall $2, %eax)), результат в стек и call печати.

 Ну, "ничего лишнего" это если не считать всех крестовых прибамбасов.

Comment: gcc без опций оптимизации тоже много всякого лишнего создает, но уже при -O2 все приходит в должный вид.

Comment: Автор пишет о компиляции с оптимизацией по скорости (и тот же результат при оптимизации по размеру).

Видимо дело в том, что это *бесплатный* продукт MS. В pro версии я думаю результат будет иным.